# Pattern-matching Seq's in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Pattern matching is one of the most elegant Haskell features.

I've been working on a project recently where I need a queue data structure so I'm using Data.Sequence.  However, it looks like I have to give up the elegance of pattern matching and resort to guards:

```
floodFillWorker :: Image -> RGBAColor -> Double -> PixelQueue -> Image
floodFillWorker image base tolerance queue 
    | Seq.null queue = image
    | otherwise      = doSomeWork image
```

Can I use pattern matching with sequences or do I need to use guards?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ephemient is on the right track with view patterns but I think there's a way to do it which is actually quite nice. `Data.Sequence` was actually written with views in mind and you should use either the `ViewL` or `ViewR` types in order to patternmatch on the data structure.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

floodFillWorker image _ _ (Seq.viewl -> EmptyL) = image
floodFillWorker image base tolerance queue = doSomeWork image
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can I also use it to pattern-match for the front and the rest, as I would with a list?

e.g.
    floodFillWorker _ _ _ (first : rest) = ....

Comment: I was considering pointing this out, but it seemed like OP didn't actually want to deconstruct the sequence here.  But if that works, then this is good.

Comment: Sorry, my original question was only half-specified.  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 6):

You *could* use [view patterns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns) instead of guards, but actually it isn't any better (IMO).  The guards look fine to me...

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

floodFillWorker image _ _ (Seq.null -> True) = image
floodFillWorker image base tolerance queue = doSomeWork image
```